# How to interpret a plot of an ordered logit model

Tags: logistic-regression

I'm running a polr regression with r because the dependent variable of this dataset is ordinal one. Then I created a plot of the effects with the Effects package.
But now I am not sure how to interpret this plot. Can I just say in general that the probability decreases to get in the lowest category of the depentent variable and increases to get in the highest category of the dependent variable if the focal predictor increases by one unit? Or can I fully interpret the plot like this: the probability to get in the second category or higher is about 20% if the AvRating has a value of zero. This probability increases up to 50 % if the AvRating has a value of 5.

The plot I am talking about looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3ruA.png)

Here you can see the R code of this plot:

```
AvRating <- c(4.250000, 5.000000, 0.000000, 3.920000, 2.333333, 0.000000)
b <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
CIB <- c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
d <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
e <- c(1, 1, 0,  1, 1, 1)
f <- c(26,  1,  1,  2,  7,  7)
g <- c(-4.000000000, -0.004364805, -4.000000000, -4.000000000, -0.004364805, -0.004364805)
mydata <- cbind(AvRating,b,CIB,d,e,f,g)



ohne1 <- polr(CIB ~ b + AvRating + d + e + f + g,
       data= mydata, method= "logistic", Hess=T)
Eff.ohne1 <- Effect(focal.predictors = "AvRating", mod= ohne1)
Eff.df <- data.frame((Eff.ohne1))
Eff.df <- Eff.df[,1:7]
neu1 <- gather(Eff.df, time, prob.X1, prob.X1:prob.X6)
ggplot(neu1, aes(x=AvRating, y=prob.X1, fill=time)) + geom_area()
```

The code works well, it's just about the interpretation.
Thanks for your help.